# Create condition in foreach loop in ASP MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foreach

Is there syntax to create a condition in the 'foreach' loop used in the view page?

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Where(item.Status != "C") {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TableName)
    </td>
    .
    .
    .
```

The syntax for this foreach is incorrect, does anyone have an idea what it should be? (The rest of the table is truncated)

Comment: Can you clarify "doesn't work" - other than missing </tr> and } at the end of it.... I'm not sure what's wrong?

Comment: edited - per your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a parenthesis on the end of the foreach line:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Where(item.Status != "C")) {
```

Answer (score 2):

```cs
@foreach (var item in Model.Items.Where(i => i.Status != "C") {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TableName)
    </td>
```